# Django Ajax The likes I push disappear when I refresh the page

Tags: django, ajax

I implemented the Like function in Django Ajax, but when I refresh the page, the Likes I have pushed disappear.
Why?

I thought there was a problem with `body:` post_pk={{ post.pk }}` and looked into it, but could not figure it out.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from accounts.models import CustomUser

class  Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-created_at"]

class Like(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    target = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
class DeletePost(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin, DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'delete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def test_func(self, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs['pk']
        post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        return (post.user == self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        like_count = self.object.like_set.count()
        context['like_count'] = like_count

        if self.object.like_set.filter(user_id=self.request.user).exists():
            context['is_user_liked'] = True
        else:
            context['is_user_liked'] = False
        return context

def like(request):
    post_pk = request.POST.get('post_pk')
    context = {'user_id': f'{ request.user }'}
    article = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post_pk)
    like = Like.objects.filter(target=article, user_id=request.user)

    if like.exists():
        like.delete()
        context['method'] = 'delete'
    else:
        like.create(target=article, user_id=request.user)
        context['method'] = 'create'
    
    context['like_count'] = article.like_set.count()

    return JsonResponse(context)
```

**detail.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        <p>タイトル：{{object.title}}</p>
        <p>投稿者：{{object.user}}</p>
        <p>コメント：{{object.content|safe}}</p>

        <div class="card-header">
            {% if is_user_liked %}
            <button type="button" id="ajax-like" style="border:none;background:none">
              <!-- すでにいいねしている時はfasクラス -->
              <i class="fas fa-heart text-danger" id="like-icon"></i>
            </button>
            {% else %}
            <button type="button" id="ajax-like" style="border:none;background:none">
              <!-- いいねしていないときはfarクラス -->
              <i class="far fa-heart text-danger" id="like-icon"></i>
            </button>
            {% endif %}
            <!-- いいねの数 -->
            <span id="like-count">{{ like_count }}</span>
            <span>いいね</span>
          </div>

        {% if object.user == request.user %}
        <a href="{% url 'myapp:update' pk=object.pk %}" class="btn btn-primary ms-3" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">編集</a>
        <a href="{% url 'myapp:delete' pk=object.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger ms-3" tabindex="-1" role="button" aria-disabled="true">削除</a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    // いいねボタンが押された時
    document.getElementById('ajax-like').addEventListener('click', e => {
      e.preventDefault();
      const url = '{% url "myapp:like" %}';
      fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: `post_pk={{ post.pk }}`,
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
          'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
        },
      }).then(response => {
        return response.json();
      }).then(response => {
        // いいね数を書き換える
        const counter = document.getElementById('like-count')
        counter.textContent = response.like_count
        const icon = document.getElementById('like-icon')
        // いいねした時はハートを塗る
        if (response.method == 'create') {
          icon.classList.remove('far')
          icon.classList.add('fas')
          icon.id = 'like-icon'
        } else {
          icon.classList.remove('fas')
          icon.classList.add('far')
          icon.id = 'like-icon'
        }
      }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: can you check 
1) if like appears in db after you press it
2) if it doesnt, create like in admin or shell and check if it renders

Comment: Change `like.create(target=article, user_id=request.user)` to `Like.objects.create(target=article, user_id=request.user)`

Comment: @raphael                                                                                                                                              Thanks for your comment.
I changed the code to the one you suggested and it didn't help, I checked admin and the like function was working fine. there may be a problem with the html.

Comment: @VladMarchenko　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　Thanks for your comment.
I checked db.sqlite3. It was showing the likes properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to change `like.create(target=article, user_id=request.user)` to `article.like_set.create(user_id=request.user)`?

Also, is the right value in the response? Can you open Django Admin and check is the new like object created or not?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Changing to article.like_set.create(user_id=request.user) did not solve the problem. when I checked admin, the like function was working fine. there might be a problem with the html.

Comment: can you also add the `DetailView`? Because, for this moment I see only the `DeletePost`

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
I had written the code in DeleteView by mistake.
I wrote it in DetailView and it solved the problem.